# Heavily edit question that is about to be closed?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/44198/how-can-i-avoid-the-risk-of-mistakenly-deleting-data-from-a-production-environme) looks like it is about to be closed (currently 4 close votes).  As written the question has received a bunch of IT centric (and scenario specific)  answers.  But it seems to have a more general question inside it: how to convey that you fear you may fail to sucessful complete a task, without appearing either incompetent or unwilling to do hard work.

If I editted the question to be more generic, all of the existing answers would suddenly become irrelevant.  Should I just let it go, and let the question be closed?  Or rewrite it and let the answers be irrelevant?

Comment: I'm on mobile so can't really say much but there is a meta post about heroic edits which is similar, I think?

Comment: @enderland do you by chance mean [Aggressive Edits](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2153/168)? FWIW with 10 answers, it would be tough to do so without invalidating some (even if you ignore two answers that seem to be quite worthless anyway, there would still be eight to keep an eye at)

Comment: Better to write a new question, and let this one go, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few situations here where this can be the case.

For some questions, such as [this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/44449/revisions) a meaningful edit early is a great idea - if you look at the first and second iteration of that post, you will see exactly where that question was headed. In cases like this it's obvious a question will be closed. A significant edit can be great in these situations.

For questions which are closed later, or have considerable numbers of answers already, it's less obvious. In the past when this has happened we (often moderators...) have gone through and left comments on all answers indicating the question was changed.

This is trickier and a *lot* more labor intensive, not just on the part of the community but also answerers.

If there is a question which is good but "lost" in the noise I'd suggest asking it yourself. A good question is a good question, even if you borrow themes from a question which was closed as off topic. A lot of the questions I've posted have been similarly inspired.

Comment: You appear to be missing half a sentence here:  "In cases like this it's obvious a "